# How to calculate weighted average of non-zero values?

Tags: algorithm, go, average

I am new to Go, I am doing the following:

I have a slice:

```
valueList := []int16{500, 400, 0, 300}
```

and a weight slice:

```
weightList := []float64{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}
```

Now I want to do this:

```
res := make([]float64, 4)
for i, value := range valueList {
    res[i] = float64(value) * weightList[i]
}
```

But as you can see, I get a `0` in `valueList`, now I want to average the weight to the others if value is not `0`, so in this example, it should be:

```
500 * (0.1 + 0.3/3) + 400 * (0.2 + 0.3/3) + 300 * (0.4 + 0.3/3)
```

If another `0` shows up, average the weight again.

How can I do this simply?

Comment: You can't have a `nil` value in a `[]int16` slice or array. That is compile time error. You should really try your example codes before posting the question.

Comment: @icza ...., so how can I have a similar thing? I am new to golang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the sum weight of non-zero values while iterating over them, and do the division by the sum weight at the end:

```
vs := []int{500, 400, 0, 300}
ws := []float64{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}

sumWeight, avg := 0.0, 0.0
for i, v := range vs {
    if v == 0 {
        continue
    }
    sumWeight += ws[i]
    avg += float64(v) * ws[i]
}
avg /= sumWeight

fmt.Println("Average:", avg)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/URqnOUBDSv)):

```
Average: 357.1428571428571
```

**Note:**

This solution does not require weights to sum up to `1.0` neither to be in the range of `0..1` (but they can't be negative).

**Note #2:**

If the input slices are empty (either by having `len == 0` or all values being `0`) or `sumWeight` of non-zero values is `0.0`, the result will be `NaN` due to dividing by `sumWeight` which is `0.0`. You might want to check this case and do something else:

```
if sumWeight > 0.0 {
    avg /= sumWeight
}
```